# Deleted messages logging not working discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create an event which prints any deleted message

here is my code

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    print(message)
```

This doesn't print anything and there aren't any errors

Maybe this has something to do with intents?

Comment: Are you using a selfbot? Try `message.content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to make the deleted message get printed would be:

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    print(message.content)
```

`message.content` contains the content of the message which gets printed upon deletion of the message.

If the message is not found in the internal message cache, then this event will not be called. This means that your bot must be running before the message that will be removed is sent.

Comment: It doesn't trigger the event, not that there is a problem with the print

Comment: The message that gets deleted must be posted after the bot is online. This is called the 'internal message cache'. If you're trying to delete a message that was posted before the bot went online, the bot will simply not see it and will not print any message.